# onNewIntent() TypeCastException on some Android Devices

Tags: android, kotlin, casting, typecasting-operator, typecast-operator

I've detected some crash via Crashlytics on some Android Devices. It is caused by `TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.my.app.service.data.model.CampaignResult` on line 83

I've updated my code multiple times to fix this so I don't know exactly which line 83 refers to

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        if(intent != null){ //I think this is line 83
            var result: CampaignResult? = null
            result = intent.getSerializableExtra(CAMPAIGN_RESULT_KEY) as? CampaignResult?
            if (result != null) campaignResult = result
        }
    }
```

CampaignResult

```
enum class CampaignResult {
    CAMPAIGN_FAILED_NETWORK,
    CAMPAIGN_FAILED_NO_DATA,
    CAMPAIGN_SUCCESS
}
```

And here's devices that suffer this problem

[image]

[image]

Please help

Comment: If you've updated your code several times, are you sure that the problem devices are running this code? There is no way that `if(intent != null)` is going to throw an exception.

Comment: @TedHopp `result = intent.getSerializableExtra(CAMPAIGN_RESULT_KEY) as? CampaignResult?` maybe this is the one caused this exception?

Comment: are you sure you use "as? CampaignResult"? if you use `as` instead of `as?` the exception will be throw

Comment: @CôngHải I'm sure, this is the latest version, I've used ```as?``` but exception is still thrown

Comment: I already decompile the kotlin code above, it only throw exception if you use this `intent.getSerializableExtra(CAMPAIGN_RESULT_KEY) as CampaignResult`

Comment: As @CôngHải points out, The assignment to `result` could through the exception if you used `as` instead of `as?`. Is it possible that you changed `as` to `as?` during one of the code updates while trying to solve the problem? If so, the crashing devices may still be running the older code. Do you have your software under version control so you can see what code is running on the version(s) that Crashlytics reports as having the problem?

Comment: @TedHopp My client tested it with his device and it's still crashing even with the newest version, so I don't know how to fix this. Maybe I should change my app logic to avoid using onNewIntent.